# Appium ios - Unknown device or simulator UDID error

Tags: python, appium, udid

I am using Apium+python to automate on Mac, and i am trying to add my new iPad and set up desired capabilities.
The iPad use a 25 character one and have a “-” in between like:
XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

When I try to use that, I get an error like one here: https://prnt.sc/1w0rukf 1

Can someone help on how to get past this?

Comment: Could you please post some code as well as the error you are receiving inline in the question. You can use "```" to delimit code blocks as in standard markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the iPad is connected?

**idevice_id -l** command returns the list of connected iOS devices.

If you get **idevice_id command not found** error message, you can install with **brew install ideviceinstaller**

If brew is not installed, you can install brew first with this command

**/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"**